# I'm getting a gpg error

Tags: updates, ppa, gnupg

I'm getting a gpg error:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: the following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available : NO_PUBKEY 5A9A06AEF9C8DB0
```

This came after doing

```
sudo apt-get-repository ppa:ok2cqr/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

The error happened after a long list of 'Hit http

can't copy/paste from the Ubuntu laptop to here, a mac desktop with a better WiFi connection, but at the time i seemed to have a reliable connection.

thanks
scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be the key that you were trying to add got expired i.e. not available on the server now.
Or
the key is entered wrongly

Check this link:
[How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

Btw,
you can manually delete keys by going into Synaptics.

About mouse.
I doubt if it has anything to do with the above error.
Check mouse settings in preferences and settings.
Something wrong there like pointer speed and acceleration.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will look into that link in a moment. As for the mouse business it got added in there in error, sorry.

Comment: I did not get anywhere, but I had fun reading and rerunning things. I sent a request to the dev by way of one of his forums and included a listing of my latest output.